# SharePointOnline/Office365 getting data from Database table to SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online

Does anyone know how we can get data from SQL Server database table to **SharePointOnline** list?

Its not a one time thing, but data should get updated from Database table to SharePoint list continuously once every 24 hrs. One way sync from DB to List?

If it would have been an OnPrem environment,there are lot of options. But so far not sure what options are there to do it in **SharePointOnline\Office365**.

Appreciate any ideas\Pointers.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

One option off the top of my head would be a scheduled task running on an on premises server that queries your DB for all the information and then uses CSOM code or REST API to submit the data to your O365 list.

Other options would be using BCS to surface the data.

Another option could be a provider hosted app the surfaces your data and makes it available in O365.

Answer (score 3):

If you have SharePoint online Plan 2(E3 and E4 plan has included it) that supports you to set up BCS.

deploy an external list on your SharePoint online. The external list displays data from an external data source. It is built on an external content type that describes the data source, and allows users to work with the data in a familiar SharePoint interface. Learn more from [Deploy a Business Connectivity Services cloud-only solution in SharePoint 2013.](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj943762.aspx)

Another Option is using the 3rd party tool.[Cloud Connector for Microsoft Office 365 and SharePoint](http://www.layer2.de/en/community/FAQs/cloud-connector/Pages/SQL-Sync-to-Office365.aspx)